# Downloading Windows OS on usb pen drive to reinstall on Lenovo ideapad 32bit

Tags: windows, boot, usb-flash-drive, uninstall, reinstall

I have the necessary software (iolo system mechanic pro)needed to wipe out my hard drive on my lenovo ideapad 32bit. I don't know much about this stuff but follow directions well. There is no cd drive. i only have a single usb flash drive drive and a usb pen (it looks like a real pen with a usb) I need to know exactly how to save my windows operating system onto my pen drive so I can wipe out my hard drive completely and then reinstall my windows OS from my usb  pen drive. I have no other source or backup to install windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this tool and guide](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) from Microsoft.

But first check if you don't have integrated reinstall procedure which will take care of the entire process (some laptops do). Look for it some keystroke hints on the boot screen (the one with manufacturer logo) or try pressing F8 when that screen disappears and look for "Repair computer" option.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows 8 or Windows 7?

If you are using Windows 8, go to your settings and there should be an option somewhere which says 'Refresh your computer' which gets rid of all your programs while keeping the files, and basically refreshing the computer.

Please leave a comment if you have any difficulties doing this.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make a bootable windows os in your pen drive follow the procedure

1. Format your pendrive with `NTFS` filesystem
2. copy windows file into the pen drive not iso but extract iso and copy to pendrive
3. You can find a program `bootsect.exe` in the boot folder of windows OS files
4. Run it as

> `bootsect.exe /NT60 I: /force`

where `I:` is the drive letter of pendrive